# GWT - Fullscreen

Tags: gwt

Is there a way to start a gwt-app in fullscreen mode (without toolbar, navigation)?

I found only a hint to open a new window:

```
Window.open("SOMEURL","SOMETITLE",    
"fullscreen=yes,hotkeys=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,
toolbar=no,resizable=no");
```

Is this the only way? 
If yes, what's the best way to use the "Window.open" (Example)?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
private native void requestFullscreen() /*-{
  var element = $doc.documentElement;

  if (element.requestFullscreen) {
    element.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) {
    element.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}-*/;
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a GWT question - this is a browser-provided API that GWT happens to wrap for you.

It's worth noting that modern browsers have a tendency to ignore some or all of these flags. For example, good luck getting Chrome to hide its address bar. The reason for this is that if they honoured all of the flags, you could write a web app which looked exactly like a desktop app and the user wouldn't know it - which is exactly what you sound like you're trying to do!

Comment: Which is a completely justified in some cases. Not everyone is a dirty thief.

Comment: I don't make the rules ;-)

Answer (score 0):

or use https://github.com/wokier/gwt-fullscreen

Caffeinate response has been used as a basis. I also added an event to be notified of fullscreen state change.